# use sum over partition by to calculate cumulative value

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following code to calculate cumulative value

```
SELECT
    iid
    ,item_id
    ,pg_purch_ind
    ,SUM_score1
    ,SUM(pg_purch_ind) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY SUM_score1 DESC, iid % 100, iid ) AS cum_pg_purch
into table2
FROM table1
```

But it has the following error "Incorrect syntax near 'order'." Does anyone know what is the issue?

Comment: you cannot run this query in any version lesser than 2012 so which version you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround for lesser versions

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT iid,
                item_id,
                pg_purch_ind,
                SUM_score1,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY item_id ORDER BY SUM_score1 DESC, iid % 100, iid ) AS rn
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT iid,
       item_id,
       pg_purch_ind,
       SUM_score1,
       cum_pg_purch
FROM   cte a
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum (pg_purch_ind)
                    FROM   cte b
                    WHERE  a.item_id = b.item_id
                           AND b.rn <= a.rn) cs (cum_pg_purch)
```

Without generating `Row_Number` it quite difficult to handle in cross apply `Where` clause because of the modulo operator

Comment: @Gavin - Yes, because you are using Older Sql Server version. `Sum()over(order by)` is introduced in `SQL SERVER 2012`